# Red Hat >= What is the difference between dnf module install nginx and dnf install nginx

Tags: redhat

Good day,

if I type dnf module list nginx, I get a listing of more recent nginx versions than if I type dnf list --showduplicates nginx.

Can you tell me what is the difference between these two types of installation, because it is not clear to me what is the difference.